# Find out filesystem type in micropython

Tags: filesystems, micropython

How does one find the filesystem type of the `/` partition in micropython?

On an ESP32 I tried formatting `/` as both Fat and Littlefs v2. Then I expected `bdev.info()` to reveal some difference but it shows exactly the same results for both:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.umount('/')
>>> os.VfsLfs2.mkfs(bdev)
>>> os.mount(bdev, '/')
>>> bdev.info()
(1, 129, 2097152, 2097152, 'vfs', False)
>>> os.umount('/')
>>> os.VfsFat.mkfs(bdev)
>>> os.mount(bdev, '/')
>>> bdev.info()
(1, 129, 2097152, 2097152, 'vfs', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the ESP32 platform use `Partition.readblocks` to read the first few bytes from the partition and find the signature of either fs:

```
from esp32 import Partition
buf = bytearray(16)
bdev.readblocks(0, buf)
if buf[8:16] == b'littlefs':
    print("LittleFS")
elif buf[3:11] == b'MSDOS5.0':
    print("FAT")
else:
    print("Unknown:", buf)
```